# Slightly unusual proof for divergence of the series of reciprocals of primes (need verification)

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, prime-numbers, divergent-series, euler-product

We know that :
$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^s} = \prod_{p} \frac{1}{1 - p^{-s}} $
From now on, assume the sum over $ n $ means $1$ to infinity. And assume that the sum or product over p means over the primes, i.e. $2, 3, 5, 7,... $

Therefore, for $ s= 1 $ we have $\sum_{n} \frac{1}{n} = \prod_{p} \frac{1}{1 - \frac{1}{p}}  $

Now we will abbreviate the harmonic series as $S_h$. Note that this series diverges. Next we will take the log of both sides.

$\implies \log(S_h) = \log(\prod_p \frac{1}{1 - \frac{1}{p}}) = \sum_p \log(\frac{1}{1 - \frac{1}{p}}) = -\sum_p \log(1 - \frac{1}{p}) $

Now we will use the Taylor series $\log(1-x) = -\sum_n \frac{x^n}{n} $ with $x = \frac{1}{p}$ to get:

$\log(S_h) = -\sum_p\bigg[-\sum_n \frac{1}{np^n} \bigg] = \sum_p \bigg[\sum_n \frac{1}{np^n} \bigg] < \sum_p \bigg[\sum_n \frac{1}{p^n} \bigg]$

Now use the formula for the geometric series starting at $n=1$, i.e. $\frac{x}{1-x}$.

$\implies \log(S_h) < \sum_p \bigg[\frac{1/p}{1 - \frac{1}{p}} \bigg] = \sum_p \frac{1}{p-1} $

And since $p>2 \implies p - 2> 0 \implies 2p -2 > p \implies p - 1> \frac{p}{2} \implies \frac{1}{p-1} < \frac{2}{p}$ we have:

$\log(S_h) < \sum_p \frac{1}{p-1} < \sum_p \frac{2}{p} $

Since $S_h$ diverges, then so does $\sum_p \frac{1}{p} $ . $\square$

I'm worried about the way I treated $S_h$ (the harmonic series), since it diverges and is not a number. I'm doing normal calculus operations on something that is not a number. But each individual step makes sense to me, so I don't know.

Comment: Maybe you should try the partial sum of S_h instead.

Comment: I think it could be made rigorous: for each partial product we have $\prod_{n=1}^N \frac{1}{1 - \frac{1}{p_n}} > \sum_{n=1}^{p_N} \frac{1}{n}$ since the left hand side can be expressed as $\sum_{n \in S} \frac{1}{n}$ where $S$ is the integers whose only prime factors are in $p_1, p_2, \ldots, p_N$.

Comment: The trouble is, if you take the partial sum in $S_h$, then the upper limit for the partial product of the primes is not at all simple, and the manipulations later on involving logs become very convoluted. I think it would be harder to complete the proof this way than the proofs that I have seen.

Comment: @DanielSchepler: If you take the product over primes that you present, it is no longer equal to the sum of *all* the number up to some $m$ of $1/n^s$.  Gaps appear.  And now you would have to show that the gaps are sparse enough that they don;t make the series converge. That seems hard.

Comment: @MarkFischler But the gaps don't start until after $p_N$ hence if you truncate the harmonic sum after $p_N$ the inequality holds.